# Entry in routing table

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing, openvpn

When I connect to my VPN service, an entry is added to my routing table which adds my new ip address (given to me by the VPN service) as the network destination, a mask of 255.255.255.255 with the gateway set to my Comcast router which is 10.0.0.1 and interface is 10.0.0.3 which is my internal ip.

Example:

```
Net Dest           Mask                Gateway       Interface     Metric
184.75.129.106     255.255.255.255     10.0.0.1      10.0.0.3      10
```

what is this specifying?

Is this a static route? Could anyone explain how it works?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would i be right in assuming that there's also a default gateway line, with a mask of `0.0.0.0`, that doesn't point to `10.0.0.1`? It looks to me like the vpn has changed your default gateway, but if you just remove the old one the packets from the vpn don't know where to go. That line looks like it's telling those packets where to go.

Answer (score 0):

In my estimation, a default gateway on a point-to-point adapter connection, which is what the vpn connections usually are, means absolutely nothing. My vpn ppp ipconfig doesn't even show a default gateway.  I know some do show one.
You normally have a route assigned for networks at the "other end" of the vpn ppp.  And those are via the vpn address.
If you have a "split tunnel" you still have the default gateway listed on the ethernet adapter for all other packets. 
If you have a "non-split" tunnel, the vpn provider is forcing everything down the ppp. You will not have a default gateway via the ethernet adapter I believe.
What does your "netstat -nr" and "ipconfig" show?
Confusing as all heck for sure.....